# Angular 2 child and parent (webpack, TS, Angular 2 final)

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

Been scratching my head since yesterday and can't figure out how to fix my problem. I have a parent: dashboard component, which includes a page header and dropdown lists. My child component contains of just one line at the moment: `"Child Component! Chosen value from dropdown list: "Some value"".` Please look at the pictures below.

The communication works fine, but I have trouble when navigating to dashboard.

My routes looks like this:

```
{
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: AdminComponent,
        },
        {
            path: 'something/:name',
            component: TestComponent,
        },
    ]
},
```

In case I do not add:

```
        {
            path: '',
            component: AdminComponent,
        },
```

in the children route, I get error:

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'admin'
Error: Cannot match any routes: 'admin'
```

But this also means, that when I have that added in children, the parent view is shown twice.

It's all fine when I choose an item from the drop down list, which triggers the child view, the view looks just like it should, parent view with drop down lists and the child text line.

I've tried to change the lines in children route:

```
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: AdminComponent,
        },
        {
            path: 'something/:name',
            component: TestComponent,
        },
    ]
```

to:

```
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'admin',
        },
        {
            path: 'something/:name',
            component: TestComponent,
        },
    ]
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Can you please provide a Plunker with your code?

Comment: Childeren and parent route `component` are same as `DashboardComponent`, don't think that will cause infinite loop?

Comment: @PankajParkar routing and component can be seen separate. only if there is some redirecting going on in the `DashboardComponent` it should work.. Not as expected though, but it works ;)

Comment: @PierreDuc got it, that was my bad assumption. Thanks for correcting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
 children: [
        {
            path: ''
        },
        {
            path: 'something/:name',
            component: TestComponent,
        },
 ]
```

This will just render nothing in your `router-outlet` on an empty path. Another option could be to redirect the empty path to `something` and have a placeholder component say: 'choose a disease'.

Comment: Perfect!! That easy, lol. Yes, this solved my problem, awesome, thanks!